# Pythagorean Theorem leg calculation

Tags: c#, math

I am making a pythagorean theorem calculator and I'm having some issues:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a, b, c;
            Console.WriteLine("Which side do you need to calculate? (a, b, c)");
            string side = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (side.ToLower())
            {
                case "a":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter length of b");
                    b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter length of c");
                    c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                    a = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b, 2) - Math.Pow(c, 2));
                    a = Math.Round(a, 4);
                    Console.WriteLine("Side a is ~ {0}", a); 

                    break;

                case "b":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter length of a");
                    a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter length of c");
                    c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    b = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) - Math.Pow(c, 2));
                    //b = Math.Round(b, 4);
                    Console.WriteLine("Side b is ~ {0}", b);
                    break;

                case "c":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter length of a");
                    a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter length of b");
                    b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    c = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2));
                    c = Math.Round(c, 4);
                    Console.WriteLine("Side a is ~ {0}", c);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I have the hypotenuse working right, but need some guidance for the other sides / legs.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming a right angle triangle
where c is the hypotenuse

```
a = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(c, 2) - Math.Pow(b, 2));
b = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(c, 2) - Math.Pow(a, 2));
c = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2));
```

looks like you had the b-c and a-c instead

Comment: watch this [kahn academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/right_triangles_topic/pyth_theor/v/pythagorean-theorem) to understand the formulas

Comment: Just as a side-note, `Math.Pow` is really not necessary as its just as easily (and probably computed faster) as, for example `a = Math.Sqrt(c * c - b * b);`

Comment: It's always the small mistakes that get you
Thanks!

@RonBeyer Fair point, I'll keep that in mind. I'll stick to Pow for now for personal clarity sake -- not that either solution is particularly complex.

Answer (score 0):

The other post pointed out what was wrong with your code but I wanted to point you are doing quite a bit of extra work in your code. Try this pattern:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Side 1");
double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter Side 2");
double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double answer = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) - Math.Pow(y, 2)); ;
answer = Math.Round(answer, 4);
Console.WriteLine("Side 3 is ~ {0}", answer);
```

You are actually overcomplicating how to get to your answer by the introduction of a 3rd variable to choose from a,b,c. I noticed this because all of the math in your 3 cases is the exact same.

Comment: It's not the same in  all cases,  one of them adds, not subtracts.

Comment: I see. So my comment of 'the math is the same' is actually false. My bad!